# How can I perform web scraping on this html code?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I currently have the following HTML code:

```
<td style="text-align:center" ></td>
     <span class="cbs-ibr" style="padding:0 0.3em 0 0; width:4.55em">112,332</span>
```

Using Python, how can i perform web scraping so that I can extract the whole line of the second line of the code? The line containing the "cbs-ibr"?

Comment: Have you tried looking for `<span>` elements with `class="cbs-ibr"`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this:
(I'm assuming you already have the soup prepared).

```
cbs-ibr_line = page_soup.find_all("td", {"class":"cbs-ibr"})
```

And to get the text only, you should do

```
cbs-ibr_line.span.text()
```

It should return you that 112,332 value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also do:

```
page_soup.findAll("span", class_="bs-ibr").text
```

Make it into a variable:

```
number = page_soup.findAll("span", class_="bs-ibr").text
```